# Visibility and Boolean expressions in C++ cycles

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void fillArray(int arr[], int size, int min, int max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % (max - (min) + 1) + (min); 
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "|" << setw(3) << arr[i];
    }
    cout << "|" << endl;
}

bool in_array(int *pArr, int n, int elem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (pArr[i] == elem)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
srand (time(0));
int arr_a [20];
int c_size = 0;
int *arr_c = new int [c_size];

fillArray(arr_a,20,1,9);
printArray(arr_a,20);


for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
int reqCount = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        if (arr_a [i] == arr_a [j])
        {
            reqCount++;
        } 
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < c_size ; j++)
    {
        if (reqCount == 2 && in_array(arr_c, c_size, arr_c[i]) != in_array(arr_c, c_size, arr_c[j]))
        {
            arr_c[c_size++] = arr_a[i];
        } 
    }
}
cout << "Result: " << endl;
printArray (arr_c,c_size);
delete[] arr_c;
return 0;
}
```

Hi Stack. 
My question about the code above is: why right now I'm getting only empty outputs.

I nearly resolved this exercise alone, but there was a problem that my output contained a lot of duplicates. That is why I created this in_array function, which should check if there are similar numbers in my output arr_c.

But it's not working properly. Can you point my error please, so I can understand why it's not showing up anything.

My output should contain only numbers that exist only in two examples in arr_a.

// I've tried to google it. But I couldn't find any similar examples to mine. I'm sorry if I'm taking your time :(

Comment: `arr_c` is a 0 element array (because `c_size` is 0 at the time you call `new`), and you never change that.  Any references to any elements of it are invalid.

Comment: `new int [c_size]` creates an array with size 0, which is not allowed in C++

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm @Timo Wait, we are currently studying dynamic massives. And in exercises before this, I was creating something similar to this and it was working properly. When code was executed, gradualy it's size was incrementing, and everything was okay. Here it is done in
 ``` arr_c[c_size++] = arr_a[i]; ```

Comment: Since `c_size` is only incremented inside the 2nd `for j` loop, that loop body will never execute.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, i got it. But everything is connected. How I can check if there are any similar numbers in arr_c with in_array function. If this function runs is based the size of arr_c which is zero, since before putting something inside it is checking it ?
It's a deadlock situation and I can't understand how to get out of it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The initial size of the array should not be 0.  Unless you got a real memory limit, you can allow yourself to create a bigger array by default, if possible, of the maximum size possible, and without using `new` (allocating it on the stack rather than the heap).

Comment: @Kerek
Yes, it shouldn't. But there is a problem. Sometimes there could be, that there will be no requested numbers in the array. Like a lot of same numbers. In this case, they won't be only TWO. So the output in fact should be empty.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @AntonioParroni The size of the array doesn't mean the amount of duplicates, thus, you can extend the array. Also, there is a simpler solution - take the original array, sort it, and run over it to remove duplicates (it is `O(nlogn)` for the sort, and `O(n)` for the second run, compared to `O(n^2)` worst case in your code)